# Why do I need the copy-and-swap idiom?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-and-swap

I can't see any point to using the copy-and-swap idiom in C++11. If I need a handle, I can use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. If I need a collection of objects, I can just `vector` or `string`.

```
struct Relax
{
   shared_ptr<Texture> resource;
public:
   /* rest of stuff */
};
```

To me, the copy-and-swap idiom sounds like a pointless thought exercise full of bugs waiting to happen.

- worry about exceptions
- do I need to worry about self-assignment or not? premature optimization is the root of all evil
- did I miss a place to call `swap` somewhere in my class's constructors?
- maybe I forgot a `delete` somewhere?

Let's say I have a compelling reason to use manual memory management. There's still allocators, swapping pointers, etc.

In **modern C++**, when would I need to do manual memory management (`new`, `delete`) w.r.t copy-and-swap?

Comment: dup of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom ?

Comment: Sounds to me that you don't know what the copy-and-swap idiom **is**.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom?rq=1): it's the very first point what CAS is for.

Comment: @user6445047 You're expected to do the bare amount of research **before** asking a question.

Comment: "when would I need to do manual memory management" Why are you assuming that you do? Did you try googling it before coming to stackoverflow?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Y'know maybe I'm missing something, but that question clearly shows manual resource management as well as everything else OP pointed in his question that he found pointless. Maybe you misread the question?